# Snap SVG: Connecting draggable shapes with lines (lines should keep being connected even after dragging )

Tags: javascript, svg, line, drag

I have reached a point where I think I need your help again. I have created 3 svg rectangles, and my goal is to be able to connect any two of those together, with a line. The thing is that my rectangles are draggable, and if two of them are connected, they need to stay connected. I have made a jsbin to test it:

https://jsbin.com/moxiyugovo/edit?html,js,console,output

The connection can be done by clicking the purple icon at the top, and then clicking once on the shapes you want to connect.

My problem is that in this way I can connect 2 shapes with a line, but when I want to make another connection, the previous line disappears. I am aware that this happens because I'm using the same var name (L) for every new line I create so they tend to overlap on top of each other. How can I differentiate those lines? Let's say I want to connect the 2 blue rectangles with each other, and the 2 red ones with each other, and keep it that way so that if any of them is dragged, the corresponding line point "follows" the shape. Thanks in advance for anyone who checks it out.

P.S. : The user is the one who needs to choose which shapes to connect, so pre-connecting them is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, I used a global variable for a line even though it's not recommended. It is functional but I will need to edit this and make it better when I get some spare time. But for anyone interested in what I mean here's a bin:

https://jsbin.com/gudabijatu/edit?html,js,output